# Is there a way to get data GUI view in Meteor.js?

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to get data GUI view in Meteor.js? 
If yes please enlighten me, as I am new to meteor. I just need to know what is the best way to  access database in meteor mongodb...
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use either:

- Z Mongo Admin, a meteor package similar to Django admin. This is
  probably the closest to what you're looking for:
  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixJyB8Z-tU8&list=UU3fBiJrFFMhKlsWM46AsAYw
- One of the many Mongo GUIs, I use both robomongo
  (http://robomongo.org/) and mongohub
  (https://github.com/bububa/MongoHub-Mac) on OSX.

Comment: Thanks, I had build my first app in meteor and now if I want to edit the database... what all steps I have to follow?

Comment: Manisha, if you want to edit the database manually, download one of the tools I mention above and then access Mongo (while Meteor is running!) on port 3002. It will take you to your database, by default your project collections will be found under the 'meteor' db.

Comment: Localhost:3002   (This will take me to Database right after downloading one of the tools mentioned above.) Is it For Windows?

Comment: That is correct. Meteor when in dev mode operate its own mongo on port 3002. When meteor is running only, of course :D

Comment: Do they support Windows or not?

Comment: Port 3001 for me, some time later.

Comment: If you want to learn more about connecting to meteor mongo with GUI client, check this comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/29417432/3757139

Answer (score 6):

I've found that this little package called Mongol is good for development to have a quick and easy way to look at your data right from within your web app.

https://github.com/msavin/Mongol

[image: Mongol Screen Shot]

Comment: This is especially useful, when running into routing problems with other, more powerful GUIs. I use mongol in an angular-meteor project, where it integrates very seamlessly.

Answer (score 2):

RoboMongo provides a good UI for Mongo DB ([Download link](https://robomongo.org/download)). When i tried with meteor, follow these steps:

- Run Meteor cd ing into your Project Folder (usually runs at http://localhost:3000/)
- Download and Install the Robomongo from the [Download link](https://robomongo.org/download)
- Create a new connection in the robomongo UI, clicking on the following icon:

  [image]

[image]

Connect to port number 3001 instead of default 27017, and you can see the mongo db and it's contents

Answer (score 1):

There's no GUI given. You can access db from command line by using `meteor mongo` while your server is running.

Comment: So, while server is running, can we write commands on command line. If yes then what is the it shows database at command line

Comment: Manisha Dayal, there's no REPL-like tool for meteor yet. I believe you can use the node debugger but it's of limited interest as Meteor abstracts a lot of what's going on behind the scenes

Comment: I think she might be referring to the in-browser javascript console as command line.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate the mention for Mongol!

I wanted to say that there is now one more option for viewing and interacting with data in your Meteor app called [Meteor Candy](https://www.meteorcandy.com). It's a little less raw than viewing JSON, which makes it far more palatable for non-developers. And of course, there is still an option to view raw JSON :)