# Connecting to Meteor Mongo from GUI

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How do I connect to my Meteor Mongo instance from a GUI, e.g. MongoChef (I am on Windows running an Ubuntu Virtual Machine which has the Meteor application on it)?

I have tried connecting using the IP address of my running Virtual Box, with both port 3001 and 27017 with no joy - should I be setting up some port forwarding or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This applies to an out-of-the-box install of Mongo when Meteor is installed:

The mongo daemon `mongod` binds to `127.0.0.1` so you need to connect to it via a SSH tunnel if your client supports it. MongoVUE and Mongo Chef both allow this type of connection. Once you SSH into the VM, you can connect to `127.0.0.1:3001` without any trouble. It does not require a password or username, just the database to be set as `meteor`.